# User avatar dimension standards or specifications

Tags: image

We have seen a user avatar will have different sizes on Facebook, Twitter, etc.

For example, Twitter has 3 different avatar sizes: 24x24, 48x48, 128x128; Facebook mainly has 50x50 and 180x180>.

I am wondering if there is a standard thumbnail size that a website should adopt, or it's all solely based on the design?

Thanks.

Comment: I hope w3c would write a spec for this in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like you say its just down to the design of your site.  If in doubt, adopt the same resolution as a big player like Twitter, and allow users to upload a larger image which will give you the flexibility to show a larger version if someone clicks through to their profile.

Answer (score 3):

I found this page to be most useful. 
https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/

I plan to allow users to upload their own larger image and using similar rules as above, any dimension within range requested will auto generate the size for that image. So no matter if I want 50px or 51px, my site will generate the first request.

Obviously that requires software custom or other and is out of scope of your tags.